# Can one configure Jenkins to fail a job if it takes too long to provision an agent?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm working with the [Jenkins AWS EC2 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin), which spawns EC2 nodes to execute Jenkins jobs. There are several cases where this plugin can hang indefinitely while waiting for a node to be provisioned. For example, if a project requires python but the EC2 image doesn't have python, Jenkins will spin up a node, fail to run the job, spin up another node, fail to run the job, spin up another node...

Meanwhile, **the job hangs forever,** Jenkins racks up an Amazon bill, and the console output looks like this:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘ec2worker’
```

Generally the solution is to just configure the EC2 cloud correctly in the first place, but easier said than done. It's easy to imagine, for instance, someone adding, say, `node.js` as a project dependency without updating the EC2 image, and then Jenkins is off to the races trying bill an AWS high score...

Ideally I could configure the plugin to **limit the number of provision attempts** before quitting, but there isn't an option for this. There is an option to limit the **total number of nodes provisioned,** but since each node is terminated after it's deemed unsuitable, Jenkins only considers there to be one active node. I.e., the number of nodes oscillates between 0 and 1, as Jenkins creates a node, discards it, and then creates another.

So I'm looking for a workaround. Is there a way to configure Jenkins to fail a build in the provisioning step? Can I limit the time it takes to create a node without limiting the total time of the whole job?

Preferably this configuration would be system-wide. But if it has to get pushed to each project config file, I imagine it looking something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        timeout(5m) {
            label 'ec2worker'
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a Jenkins feature or plugin that does something like this?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I couldn't find anything in Jenkins that did what I wanted -- though the Jenkins EC2 Plugin does seem to have a ticket in to support this missing feature.

I solved the problem in AWS with a lambda. The lambda is triggered whenever Jenkins destroys an instance, and from that event the lambda calculates how long the instance was alive. If it wasn't long enough (less than the idle period the node normally waits for), then Jenkins must be hanging and the lambda kills the job.